How to set authentication.forms.timeout in web.config to a value from <appsettings>?
How can I set the Forms Authentication timeout value to a value set in <appsettings>?
The reason for wanting this is that the same timeout value is hardcoded in a .ts file which is able to get values from <appsettings>.
So to avoid hardcoding the value in TypeScript, I'd like to be able to store the value once in <appsettings> and read it from there in both the <forms> section in the web.config file, and in the TypeScript file.
Here's my web.config file:
<!-- Majority of xml left out for brevity -->
<appSettings>
    <add key="timeoutInMins" value="60" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="60" /> <!-- How can I set this to timeoutInMins? -->
    </authentication>
</system.web>


I found a work around:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78258523/2063755
